# Vue Component inside table

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component

I created Vue Component inside Laravel Project

**TableComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

i want to display it in

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<div id="id">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <table-component></table-component>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Vue documentation is a really good place to start https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: No, Culpeper. OP's problem is related to Laravel documentation. LKN, Google. Internet is full of examples how to use Vue with Laravel.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky I used to use Vue Components in Laravel Projects.. but this question is not I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting and looking out my code. I solved it by adding  in **welcome.blade.php**. Maybe because I added , I need to add .
THANKS!